# Sails.js dot in route param

Tags: sails.js

I am trying to get this route to work

```
items/images/myimg.jpg
```

It responses 404 but work with

```
items/images/myimg
```

Also works with

```
items/images/myimg.jpg/
```

I tried the following router configuration

```
'get /items/images/:imageName': {
  action: 'items/images/find',
  skipAssets: true,
}
```

EDIT:

If I set `skipAssets: false` then the response will be unauthorized. I have the following ACL

```
'*': false,
'items/images/find': 'isLoggedIn',
```

In the isLoggedIn.js policy the req.session is undefined even when the user has a valid session.

if I set `'items/images/find': true` it will work but I want access control for this route.

Comment: From the [docs](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/routes/custom-routes#?route-target-options) `Set skipAssets to true if you don't want the route to match URLs with dots in them`

Comment: Updated my question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The route should be set like this:

```
'get /items/images/:imageName': {
  action: 'items/images/find',
  skipAssets: false,
}
```

This method should be added to **config/session.js:**

```
isSessionDisabled: function (req){
  // Allow session for all item image requests.
  if (req.path.match(/^\/items\/images\//) { 
    return false; 
  }
  // Otherwise, disable session for all requests that look like assets.
  return !!req.path.match(req._sails.LOOKS_LIKE_ASSET_RX);
}
```

More can be read about this here:
https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/4216#issuecomment-337613995

Comment: How will you handle 'get /:imageName' ?